# Ball bounce issue in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry, bounce

[edit]

I was really stupid, all is working fine now.
So forget about this dummy question!

The rotation of the main clip was a big mistake.

I've changed this by adding a var called _rota with getter and setters.

I had not to rotate the clip but just to place another Sprite in it, so I can place the sub-Sprite in the right direction by using a simple function.
So I avoid all those loops...

My mistake SRY.

I just added a Sprite which have the rotation of the Main Sprite.
Changing the rotation of the main Sprite was the reason of this issue...
So, thank you and forget about this unclear question!!! :)

```
private function drawLine():void{
        if(!clip){
            clip = new Sprite();
            addChild(clip);
        }
        var g:Graphics = clip.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.lineStyle(1,0xffffff,1);
        g.beginFill(0xffffff,1);
        g.drawCircle(Math.sin(rota)*this.width/4,Math.cos(rota)*this.height/4,3);
        g.endFill();
    }
```

I was changing the rotation property of the clip, so it was usefulness
Now I have a pretty good result.
Solved...

Sorry again...

As you can see the particles are now set in the right direction an I have no more hitTest issues...

[image]

Particles are now moving on the direction showed by the white points.

[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I need to set a Sprite in the right direction when the Ball instance change it's "pseudo rotation" (I avoid here the hitTest features)...

I've now two classes...
Do you thing I'm searching in the bright side of code or is it totally unclear? ;)

This is just a test, and I didn't spent time to code since a few years.
So this test is just to revise some basics about trigonometry...
Don't hesitate, to be rude if I'm wrong!

My new class Main :

```
package com
{
import com.display.Ball;

import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

[SWF(width = "400", height = "300", frameRate = "60", backgroundColor = "#dddddd")]
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var b1:Ball;
    private var b2:Ball;
    private var b3:Ball;
    private var b4:Ball;
    private var b5:Ball;
    private var testClip:Sprite;
    private const ANGLE_TOP_LEFT:int=135;
    private const ANGLE_BOTTOM_LEFT:int=-135;
    private const ANGLE_TOP_RIGHT:int=45;
    private const ANGLE_BOTTOM_RIGHT:int=-45;

    public function Main()
    {
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        trace("stageSize = " + getStageSize() + ", fps = " + stage.frameRate);
        drawlineGuides();
        addBalls();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,onStageResize);
    }
    private function addBalls():void{
        b1 = new Ball(500/2,250/2,10);
        addChild(b1);
        b1.color = 0x6666cc;
        b1.rota = 135;
        b1.drawBall();
        b1.move(5); 

        b2 = new Ball(100,100,10);
        addChild(b2);
        b2.color = 0xff9900;
        b2.rota = -110;
        b2.drawBall();
        b2.move(4);

        b3 = new Ball(50,80,10);
        addChild(b3);
        b3.color = 0xff0000;
        b3.rota = 60;
        b3.drawBall();
        b3.move(3);

        b4 = new Ball(75,20,10);
        addChild(b4);
        b4.color = 0x00aa00;
        b4.rota = 10;
        b4.drawBall();
        b4.move(4);

        b5 = new Ball(125,130,10);
        addChild(b5);
        b5.color = 0x8457a2;
        b5.rota = -45;
        b5.drawBall();
        b5.move(4);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b1.pauseResume);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b2.pauseResume);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b3.pauseResume);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b4.pauseResume);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,b5.pauseResume);
    }
    private function rotate(e:Event):void{
        testClip.rotation = b2.rotation-45;
    }
    private function getStageSize():Point{
        var p:Point= new Point(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
        return p;
    }
    private function drawlineGuides():void{
        var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1);
        g.moveTo(0,stage.stageHeight/2);
        g.lineTo(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight/2);
        g.moveTo(stage.stageWidth/2,0);
        g.lineTo(stage.stageWidth/2,stage.stageHeight);
    }
    private function onStageResize(e:Event):void{
        drawlineGuides();
    }
}
}
```

And here is my new class Ball :

```
package com.display
{
/* this import is optionnal
if you want to run this class without the BongSound instance
comment all lines where the var bSound is called
*/
//import com.media.sound.BongSound;

import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.media.Sound;

public class Ball extends Sprite
{
    private var _radius:int;
    private var _rotation:Number;
    private var _color:int;
    private var _g:Graphics;
    private var _g2:Graphics;
    private var _speed:Number;
    private var speedx:Number;
    private var speedy:Number;
    public var rota:Number;
    private var smallCircle:Sprite;
    private var rendered:Boolean = false;
    public var paused:Boolean = false;
    private const ZERO:uint = 0;
    //private var bSound:BongSound;
    /**
     * Ball(posx:Number,posy:Number,radius:uint)<br/>
     * this constructor create an instance of a bouncing ball<br/>
     * the posx and posy must be included in the range of the defined stageWidth and stageHeight!<br/>
     * Otherwise, the ball will be placed in the stage range.
     */
    public function Ball(posx:Number,posy:Number,radius:uint)
    {
        //bSound = new BongSound();
        smallCircle = new Sprite();
        this.addChild(smallCircle);
        this._radius = radius;
        this.x = posx;
        this.y = posy;
        _g = this.graphics;
        _g2 = smallCircle.graphics;
    }
    private function checkStageSize():void{
        if(this.x + radius + speedx >= this.stage.stageWidth){
            this.x = this.stage.stageWidth - this.width;
        }
        if(this.y + radius + speedy >= this.stage.stageHeight){
            this.y = this.stage.stageHeight - this.height;
        }
        if(this.x - radius + speedx <= ZERO){
            this.x = this.width;
        }
        if(this.y - radius + speedy <= ZERO){
            this.y = this.height;
        }
    }
    public function get speed():Number
    {
        return _speed;
    }
    public function set speed(value:Number):void
    {
        _speed = value;
    }
    public function get color():int
    {
        return _color;
    }
    public function set color(value:int):void
    {
        _color = value;
    }
    public function get radius():int
    {
        return _radius;
    }
    public function set radius(value:int):void
    {
        _radius = value;
    }
    /**
     * drawBall()<br/>
     * this function draws the main Ball Object
     */
    public function drawBall():void
    {
        _g.clear();
        _g.lineStyle(1,0x666666,1);
        _g.beginFill(_color,1);
        _g.drawCircle(0,0,this._radius);
        _g.endFill();
        _g.lineStyle(1,0x666666,1);
        _g.beginFill(0xffffff,1);
        _g.endFill();
    }
    /**
     * drawPoint()<br/>
     * this function draws the Point Object wich is placed in the direction/rotation of the main Ball instance.
     */
    public function drawPoint():void{
        _g2.clear();
        _g2.lineStyle(1,0x666666,1);
        _g2.beginFill(0xffffff,1);
        _g2.drawCircle(ZERO, ZERO, this._radius/2);
        smallCircle.x = Math.sin(deg2rad(rota+90))*this.radius/2;
        smallCircle.y = Math.cos(deg2rad(rota+90))*this.radius/2;
        _g2.endFill();
    }
    /**
     * move(speed:Number):void<br/>
     * this function set the speed and makes the Ball move.<br/>
     * The displace function is called when an ENTER_FRAME event is triggered.
     */
    public function move(speed:Number):void{
        this.speed = speed;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,displace);
    }
    /**
     * getRota():Number<br/>
     * this function returns the rotation of the Ball instance.<br/>
     * the rotation is returned in degrees.
     */
    public function getRota():Number{
        return rad2deg(Math.atan2(speedy,speedx));
    }
    /**
     * pauseResume(e:MouseEvent):void
     * Pause or resume movement.
     */
    public function pauseResume(e:MouseEvent):void{
        switch(paused){
            case false:
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,displace);
                paused = true;
                break;
            case true:
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,displace);
                paused = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    /**
     * checkBounds():void<br/>
     * <p>
     * this function plays a Sound when the Ball instance hit the bounds.<br/>
     * the rota variable is updated (even if the rotation of the Ball instance don't change).<br/>
     * If the stage is resized, a call to checkStageSize() set the positions x & y in the bounds of the Stage.
     * </p>
     * @see checkStageSize()
     */
    private function checkBounds():void{
        if(this.x + radius + speedx >= this.stage.stageWidth){
            //bSound.play();
            rota = rad2deg(Math.atan2(-speedy,-speedx));
        }
        if(this.y + radius + speedy >= this.stage.stageHeight){
            //bSound.play();
            rota = rad2deg(Math.atan2(speedy,speedx));
        }
        if(this.x - radius + speedx <= ZERO){
            //bSound.play();
            rota = rad2deg(Math.atan2(-speedy,-speedx));
        }
        if(this.y - radius + speedy <= ZERO){
            //bSound.play();
            rota = rad2deg(Math.atan2(speedy,speedx));
        }
        checkStageSize();
    }
    /**
     * <p>
     * displace(e:Event):void
     * displace the ball and calls drawPoint to place the sub-Sprite depending of the "rotation" of the Ball instance.</p>
     * @see #drawPoint()
     * @see #checkBounds()
     */
    private function displace(e:Event):void{
        checkBounds();
        speedx = Math.sin(deg2rad(rota+90))*speed;
        speedy = Math.cos(deg2rad(rota+90))*speed;
        this.x += speedx;
        this.y += speedy;
        drawPoint();
    }
    public function deg2rad(value:Number):Number{
        return value/180*Math.PI;
    }
    public function rad2deg(value:Number):Number{
        return value*180/Math.PI;
    }

}
}
```

PrintScreens :
[image]
[image]

It is now possible to continue the moves even when the Stage is Resized avoiding the issues I had in the past...

Comment: I hope that the meaning of the "pseudo-rotation" make sense in this context. :( ???
If you have some time, could you test those 2 classes (there's no element in the library).
Can you please tell me if I'm looking in the right direction or if this stays unclear???
Thank you a lot.

Comment: This may help to understand why I'm using the Math.atan2 in the checkBounds() function I hope..

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out at me is you're potentially modifying the position of both `x` and `y` properties twice.

If you run the logic once, and store your directionality, then you should be able to update the position of your ball in one go.

Replace your `moveBall` function with the following...

```
private var h:int = 1;
private var v:int = 1;
public function moveBall(e:Event):void {
    speedx = Math.sin(deg2rad(rotation+90))*speed;
    speedy = Math.cos(deg2rad(rotation+90))*speed;

    if (x + radius + (speedx * h) > this.loaderInfo.width || (x + (speedx * h) - radius < 0)) {
        h *= -1;
    }

    if (y + radius + (speedy * v) > this.loaderInfo.height || (y + (speedx * v) - radius < 0)) {
        v *= -1;
    }

    this.x += (speedx * h);
    this.y += (speedy * v);
}
```

Comment: if you set the rotation to 60 in the Main class as this : b1.rotation = 60; You get the same issue...

Comment: Wow, I totally missed the fact that you were rotating it.  I'll revise the answer with a solution in a bit.

Comment: All is working fine now.
I'm sorry about those repeated edits.
Things are easy when the code is clear, efficient and run faster.
That's the reason why I voted up your answer even it was not solving my problem at glance.
So you don't need to try to find another answer.
I was wrong...
Forgive me about this.